# Is there a more elegant way of formulating this Python loop?

Tags: python, loops

my question is related to Python loops in general.

I've created a loop that iterates through each item in an XML object. It then appends the retrieved value to a result list. Is there a more elegant or compact way to write this? Best practices?

```
i = 0
result = []

tree = ET.fromstring(webdata)
counts = tree.findall('.//count')

for count in counts:
    result.append(int(counts[i].text))
    i += 1
```

Comment: Simply `result = [int(count.text) for count in counts]`...

Answer (score 4):

You can do a [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions):

```
result = [int(count.text) for count in tree.findall('.//count')]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use map

```
result = map(lambda x: int(x.text), counts)
```